# Filtering a words in a listview items by a textbox

Tags: c#, listview, filter

I have a `ListView` with items, and I want to make a filter, which gonna show me only items which contain a word written in a `TextBox`. I tried:

```
bool containsAnyLetter = textBox2.Text.IndexOfAny(letters) >= 0;
```

That's the code for filling `ListView`:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    listView2.Items.Clear();
    int places, count;
    string keyword, site;
    count = 1;
    keyword = keywords.Text;
    site = sites.Text;
    places = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    var client = new GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com");
    var results = client.Search(keyword, places);
    foreach (var webResult in results)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.Add(count++ + "  " + webResult.ToString());

        item.SubItems.Add(string.Empty);            

        ListViewItem itemz = listView2.Items.Add(webResult.Url.ToString());
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
    }
}
```

Now I want to do something like that, but it have to exchange the current listview items, to only that which contains the word in the `TextBox`.

```
if (listView2.Items.ToString().Contains(textBox2.Text))
{
    //the should exchange the listview items for a that one's which contains a word from a textbox.
}
```

But it doesn't seems to be working well. Is there any other way to find and show the items which contain a word in a `TextBox`?

Comment: That was just an example, I don't know what code should I use for finding an item in a listview.

Comment: Well, no it's not the listView. I'm using google api to fill the url's in the listview.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, sorry. But look there: http://wklej.org/hash/f10097c59c9/

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 3):

Another method of doing it would be to cast the ListView items to an IEnumerable and use Linq to do the query.

```
IEnumerable<ListViewItem> lv = listViewItems.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();

var matchingItems = lv.Where(i => i.Text.Contains(textBoxCriteria.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `Listbox` and check if the item contains the word, but you can't *hide* the item, because a ListBox can't do that. You have to choices:
1. Hide the actual ListBox and create a new one at the same spot OR
2. Use WPF.
Use this code to check if the item contains the text in the textbox:

```
foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
{
    if(listBoxItem.ToString().Contains(txtBox.Text))
    {
        //Item contains word, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's simpler to hide the actual ListBox and show a filtered version instant of removing each item and place them back at the same index. In WPF I would build a simple ListBox which is able to hide and show items and would implement it via the `WpfHost` Control